# What's the best way to define an independent method to be reusable by two non-related classes?

Tags: java

I've two classes that need to use the same method and I believe inheritance is overkill since this is the only thing in common: there are no relations and the operation is very specific. 
The method to be reused just take two parameters and calculate an operation with them.

Comment: You could encapsulate it into another class and use composition instead of inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like a utility method. So, I think a separate class containing that method as a static method would do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Composition is a possible solution here. The 2 classes could be passed on one instance of a 'helper' class with your operation.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I would create a utility class for this kind of thing - most likely using a static method.

Answer (score 0):

If the method does not use any instance fields: make it static and move it into some utility class.